# Removing google 'click' map markers

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-api

I'm working on implementing a Google map into my website, however I find it very annoying that when ever I click on a location the marker that gets added, can't be removed. If someone has an idea how to remove only the added markers as well as how to make the bounce animation only occur when a user clicks on the centered marker?

Here is my code:

```
function myMap() {
    var myCenter =new google.maps.LatLng(-34.035088, 23.046469);
    var mapCanvas = document.getElementById("googleMap");
    var mapOptions = {center: myCenter, zoom: 11,
        panControl: true,
        zoomControl: true,
        mapTypeControl: true,
        scaleControl: true,
        streetViewControl: true,
        overviewMapControl: true,
        rotateControl: true,
        mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position:myCenter, 
animation:google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE});
        marker.setMap(map);
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', 
function() {
    var pos = map.getZoom();
        map.setZoom(15);
        map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
        window.setTimeout(function(){map.setZoom(pos);},3000);
    });
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: 'Welcome to Knysna!'
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.open(map,marker);
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
        placeMarker(map, event.latLng);
    });
    function placeMarker(map, location) {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: location,
        map: map
        });
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: 'Latitude: ' + location.lat() +
            '<br>Longitude: ' + location.lng()
        });
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove `marker` and add `BOUNCE` toggle event.

Use those documents that I used to figure the problem.

Animation: [Bounce](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-animations)

Marker: [Remove Marker](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-remove)

Hope that will answer your questions.

```
function myMap() {
  var myCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.035088, 23.046469);
  var mapCanvas = document.getElementById('googleMap');
  var markers = []; /*Store new marker in array*/
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  var mapOptions = {
    center: myCenter,
    zoom: 10,
    panControl: true,
    zoomControl: true,
    scaleControl: true,
    streetViewControl: true,
    overviewMapControl: true,
    rotateControl: true,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myCenter,
    map: map,
    id: 'Knysna'
  });
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: 'Welcome to Knysna!'
  });
  markers.push(marker); // Push new marker to array.
  // Event Listeners
  marker.addListener('click', function() {
    toggleBounce();
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    var pos = map.getZoom();
    map.setZoom(15);
    map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
//     window.setTImeout(function() {
//       map.setZoom(pos);
//     }, 3000);
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
    placeMarker(map, event.latLng);
  });
  // Animation
  function toggleBounce() {
    if(marker.getAnimation() !== null) {
      marker.setAnimation(null);
    } else {
      marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
    }
  }
  // Marker
  function placeMarker(map, location) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: location,
      map: map
    });
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: 'Latitude: ' + location.lat() +
            '<br>Longitude: ' + location.lng() + '<br><button id=\'del\'>Delete</button>'
    });
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
    infowindow.addListener('domready', function() {
      var delButton = document.getElementById('del');
      delButton.onclick = function() {
        marker.setMap(null);
      }
    })
    markers.push(marker);
  }
}
```

JSBin: [Solution](https://jsbin.com/tesapeh/edit?js,output)